openpyxl creates incorrect sheet names within for loop
This is my code:
import os
import sys
my_path = 'C:/Users/S.Fazlollahzadeh/Desktop/shell-scripts/test only/excel'
os.chdir(my_path)
sys.path.append(my_path)
from openpyxl import Workbook

names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4']
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

for name in names:
        ws.title = name
        wb.create_sheet(name)

wb.save("sample.xlsx")
quit()

Sheet names are:
name4
name11
name21
name31
name41

While it should be:
name1
name2
name3
name4

What am I doing wrong?

The problem is that you are creating worksheets with the name that already exist.
Correct way to create worksheet is one of the following:
wb = Workbook()
ws_first = wb.active
ws_first.title = names[0]

for name in names[1:]:
    ws = wb.copy_worksheet(ws_first)
    ws.title = name


wb.save("sample1.xlsx")

or:
wb = Workbook()
wb.active.title = names[0]

for name in names[1:]:    
    ws = wb.create_sheet(name)

wb.save("sample2.xlsx")


Thanks. Your second way creates an additional sheet named Sheet. But first method works as expected

thx, fixed the code in the second example.

the problem is that you're renaming the active sheet to one of your names, then attempting to create a sheet with the same name (wb.create_sheet(name)), generating a sheet with {name}1 instead. You're also not switching your active sheet
you could remove the line ws.title = name and delete the original active sheet from the workbook (switching to a different sheet if you have more work in the script)
from openpyxl import Workbook
names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4']
wb = Workbook()

for name in names:
    wb.create_sheet(name)

del wb["Sheet"] # delete original active sheet
ws = wb.active # get the active sheet here if more work
# alternative ws = wb['name1']

print(wb._sheets)
# <Worksheet "name1">
# <Worksheet "name2">
# <Worksheet "name3">
# <Worksheet "name4">

